Upgrader shows incorrect upgrader alert popup
I downloaded version 1.0.24 from TestFlight for testing purposes. However, the upgrader shows the following popup message:

"Would you like to update the app?"
"A new version is available from the App Store. You are currently using version 1.0.24."
"Would you prefer to update now?"

My App Store version is 1.0.23, while my TestFlight version is 1.0.24. The TestFlight version is higher compared to the App Store version, so the upgrader popup should not appear in this scenario.
Expected Behavior:
The upgrader should recognize that the TestFlight version is newer than the App Store version and should not prompt for an update.
Current Behavior:
The popup incorrectly suggests that an update is needed, even though the TestFlight version is higher.
I downloaded version 1.0.24 from TestFlight for testing and noticed that the upgrader displayed a popup message indicating that a new version is available in the App Store, even though the App Store version is actually 1.0.23. I expected the upgrader to recognize that the TestFlight version (1.0.24) is newer and not show the update prompt.
Upgrader Package Info

https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader/versions/10.3.0


How's bout the build versions? Example: 1.0.23 + 12 --> 12 is build version.

@Nguyenfamily Testflight build version is version 1.0.24 build 1, 2 ....

maybe you forgot the increase build version on Testflight?

app store version is 1.0.23 and testflight version is 1.0.24. testflight higher then app store. so why upgrader popup showing? this is problem

I mean, build number. 1.0.23 is version, and +12 is build number. Maybe you  forgot to inscrease build number?

No @Nguyenfamily, I was always increase build number
